# Интеграция сортировки по цене в фильтр

Tags: jquery

```js
$(".select").change(function(){

  // список доступных фильтров
  var filters = $(".select").toArray().map( function(v){
                    return $(v).data('filter');
                });
                
  // проверяем все элементы списка
  $("#items li").each(function(idx, li){
      var show = true;       // по умолчанию показываем
      
      // сверяем все data- атрибуты доступных фильтров
      $.each(filters, function(fIdx, fname){  
          // значение селекта фильтра    
          var fv = $(".select-" + fname + " :selected").data('sort');
                    
          if(fv == 'all') return true;
                  
          // сверяям значение селекта с дата-атрбутом
          if( $(li).data(fname) != fv){
              show = false;
              return false;
          } 
      });
      
      $(this).toggle(show);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select select-type" data-filter="type">
    <option value="all" data-sort="all">All</option>
    <option value="2" data-sort="pistol">Pistol</option>
    <option value="3" data-sort="riffle">Riffle</option>
    <option value="4" data-sort="smg">SMG</option>
</select>

<select class="select select-class" data-filter="class">
    <option value="all" data-sort="all">Все</option>
    <option value="2" data-sort="Base Grade">Base Grade</option>
    <option value="3" data-sort="Extraordinary">Extraordinary</option>
    <option value="4" data-sort="Industrial Grade">Industrial Grade</option>
</select>

<select class="select2">
    <option value="1">Сначала дорогие</option>
    <option value="2">Сначала дешевые</option>
</select>

<ul id="items">
  <li data-type="pistol" data-class="Base Grade" data-price="10" >Item 1 (Pistol,Base Grad, 10)</li>
  <li data-type="pistol" data-class="Base Grade" data-price="20">Item 2 (Pistol,Base Grad, 20)</li>
  <li data-type="smg" data-class="Extraordinary" data-price="15">Item 3 (smg,Extraordinary, 15)</li>
  <li data-type="riffle" data-class="Extraordinary" data-price="30">Item 4 (riffle,Extraordinary, 30)</li>
  <li data-type="riffle" data-class="Industrial Grade" data-price="5">Item 5 (riffle,Industrial Grade, 5)</li>
  <li data-type="riffle" data-class="Industrial Grade" data-price="10">Item 6 (riffle,Industrial Grade, 10)</li>
  <li data-type="smg" data-class="Industrial Grade" data-price="50">Item 7 (smg,Industrial Grade, 50)</li>
  <li data-type="smg" data-class="Extraordinary" data-price="25">Item 8 (smg,Extraordinary, 25)</li>
</ul>
```

Сообственно нужна сортировка по цене, по параметру `data-price`, желательно интегрировать в фильтрацию. Под словом интегрировать я имею ввиду, чтобы при изменении параметров фильтрации - сортировка учитывалась тоже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не брать в расчет одновременную сортировку по нескольким полям, то будет как то так.

```js
$(".select-filter").change(function(){

  // список доступных фильтров
  var filters = $(".select-filter").toArray().map( function(v){
                    return $(v).data('filter');
                });
                
  // проверяем все элементы списка
  $("#items li").each(function(idx, li){
      var show = true;       // по умолчанию показываем
      
      // сверяем все data- атрибуты доступных фильтров
      $.each(filters, function(fIdx, fname){  
          // значение селекта фильтра    
          var fv = $(".select-" + fname + " :selected").data('sort');
                    
          if(fv == 'all') return true;
                  
          // сверяям значение селекта с дата-атрбутом
          if( $(li).data(fname) != fv){
              show = false;
              return false;
          } 
      });
      
      $(this).toggle(show);
  });

});

$(".select-sort").change(function(){
   var order = $(this).val();
   
   var items = $("#items li").sort(function(a,b){
                       var av = $(a).data('price');
                       var bv = $(b).data('price');
                       return order == 'desc' ? av-bv : bv-av;
                   });
   $(items).detach().appendTo("#items");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select-filter select-type" data-filter="type">
    <option value="all" data-sort="all">All</option>
    <option value="2" data-sort="pistol">Pistol</option>
    <option value="3" data-sort="riffle">Riffle</option>
    <option value="4" data-sort="smg">SMG</option>
</select>

<select class="select-filter select-class" data-filter="class">
    <option value="all" data-sort="all">Все</option>
    <option value="2" data-sort="Base Grade">Base Grade</option>
    <option value="3" data-sort="Extraordinary">Extraordinary</option>
    <option value="4" data-sort="Industrial Grade">Industrial Grade</option>
</select>

<select class="select-sort" data-sort="price">
    <option value="asc">Сначала дорогие</option>
    <option value="desc">Сначала дешевые</option>
</select>

<ul id="items">
  <li data-type="pistol" data-class="Base Grade" data-price="10" >Item 1 (Pistol,Base Grad, 10)</li>
  <li data-type="pistol" data-class="Base Grade" data-price="20">Item 2 (Pistol,Base Grad, 20)</li>
  <li data-type="smg" data-class="Extraordinary" data-price="15">Item 3 (smg,Extraordinary, 15)</li>
  <li data-type="riffle" data-class="Extraordinary" data-price="30">Item 4 (riffle,Extraordinary, 30)</li>
  <li data-type="riffle" data-class="Industrial Grade" data-price="5">Item 5 (riffle,Industrial Grade, 5)</li>
  <li data-type="riffle" data-class="Industrial Grade" data-price="10">Item 6 (riffle,Industrial Grade, 10)</li>
  <li data-type="smg" data-class="Industrial Grade" data-price="50">Item 7 (smg,Industrial Grade, 50)</li>
  <li data-type="smg" data-class="Extraordinary" data-price="25">Item 8 (smg,Extraordinary, 25)</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: До выполнения сортировки: http://f6.s.qip.ru/GjeazU7m.png после: http://f4.s.qip.ru/GjeazU7l.png

Comment: понял свою ошибку, спасибо! То что надо!

Answer (score 2):

```js
var list = $('#items'),
  listCollection;

$(".select2").change(function() {
  listCollection = $('#items>li');
  var sort = $(this).val();
  listCollection.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (sort == 1) {
      return ($(a).data('price')) > ($(b).data('price')) ? 1 : -1;
    } else if (sort == 0) {
      return ($(a).data('price')) > ($(b).data('price')) ? -1 : 1;
    }
  });
  list.html(listCollection);
});

$(".select2").trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select select-type" data-filter="type">
    <option value="all" data-sort="all">All</option>
    <option value="2" data-sort="pistol">Pistol</option>
    <option value="3" data-sort="riffle">Riffle</option>
    <option value="4" data-sort="smg">SMG</option>
</select>

<select class="select select-class" data-filter="class">
    <option value="all" data-sort="all">Все</option>
    <option value="2" data-sort="Base Grade">Base Grade</option>
    <option value="3" data-sort="Extraordinary">Extraordinary</option>
    <option value="4" data-sort="Industrial Grade">Industrial Grade</option>
</select>

<select class="select2">
    <option value="0">Сначала дорогие</option>
    <option value="1">Сначала дешевые</option>
</select>

<ul id="items">
  <li data-type="pistol" data-class="Base Grade" data-price="10">Item 1 (Pistol,Base Grad, 10)</li>
  <li data-type="pistol" data-class="Base Grade" data-price="20">Item 2 (Pistol,Base Grad, 20)</li>
  <li data-type="smg" data-class="Extraordinary" data-price="15">Item 3 (smg,Extraordinary, 15)</li>
  <li data-type="riffle" data-class="Extraordinary" data-price="30">Item 4 (riffle,Extraordinary, 30)</li>
  <li data-type="riffle" data-class="Industrial Grade" data-price="5">Item 5 (riffle,Industrial Grade, 5)</li>
  <li data-type="riffle" data-class="Industrial Grade" data-price="10">Item 6 (riffle,Industrial Grade, 10)</li>
  <li data-type="smg" data-class="Industrial Grade" data-price="50">Item 7 (smg,Industrial Grade, 50)</li>
  <li data-type="smg" data-class="Extraordinary" data-price="25">Item 8 (smg,Extraordinary, 25)</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Хорошее решение! Спасибо.